# Dynamic Data Exchange in Ubuntu using Tcl

Tags: tcl, dde

I need to access some data in Windows, for this I want to use DDE (Dynamic Data Exchange) provided by tcl language. I found this link in google http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man3/dde.3tcl.html#contenttoc4 , but I didn't have success. Somebody can help me ?

I have tcl installed in my Ubuntu 12.04, but when I call 'dde' in tclsh I have this message "invalid command name 'dde' "

Comment: It only makes sense for this command to be available where Tcl is installed in a Microsoft Windows OS, as documented on [the command's man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/dde.htm)

Comment: also asked here: http://askubuntu.com/q/350371/10127

Comment: Wait: you want to access data in windows and use ubuntu for that?

Comment: DDE is based on the Windows message pump.

Comment: I disagree, DDE is a technology created by Microsoft, but in Ubuntu I have the command dde inside Tcl as appears here
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man3/dde.3tcl.html#contenttoc4 or in other words yes I can access shared data in Windows, but I don't know how...
Johannes, I have an application running in Windows XP using DDE , COMSrv is an utility for decoding data from serial ports and then make the data available to other applications through DDE (a Windows standard for Dynamic Data Exchange).

Comment: About COMSrv you can learning more here http://www.options.no/Default.aspx?tabid=25 , VIGRA is the core software and COMSrv live  inside it.

Comment: Yes, I put the same question in askubuntu ;)'

Comment: To quote from the page you posted: `This  command allows an application to send Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE) 
       command when running under Microsoft Windows`. You run ubuntu, right? The `dde` package is part of the core, and so is the `registry` package. But both of them are only useful on windows.

Comment: Or an other example: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man3/tk_mac.3tk.html - BTW, DDE is local only, it does not work on remote machines.

Comment: You're allowed to be sitting on an Ubuntu machine writing Tcl scripts to run on a Windows machine. Cross-development is a real thing.

Answer (score 3):

DDE is fundamentally tied to the Windows messaging system; it does not work on any other platform and attempting to `package require dde` will fail (with a clean, `catch`able error). All you can do on Ubuntu with the `dde` package is write scripts that will use DDE *when run on Windows*. Of course, it's entirely legal to do just that: you don't have to be coding on the platform that you're developing for, and cross-development has been done by people for many years.

An approximate equivalent to the `dde` package is Tk's [`send`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/send.htm) command, though the details of capabilities and use are substantially different.

---

A closer *moral* equivalent for DDE-like things on Ubuntu would be [a DBus integration package](http://dbus-tcl.sourceforge.net), but that's not currently part of Tcl or Tk. (I've no idea if it is working, or available via your system's package manager.) If it works for you and you believe that that package ought to be distributed with Tcl in the future, please contact the [Tcl Core Team](http://www.tcl.tk/community/coreteam/) to make a case for doing so.

Comment: FWIW, I can't test whether dbus-tcl works; the systems I use don't run DBus…

Comment: Does appear active though; last commit was only a few weeks ago.